# SQL Form Query - Show or don't show null columns based on checkbox

Tags: sql

How can I set up the query to:
Select or not select rows with a certain column having a null value, with the choice of selecting or not selecting coming from the user clicking a checkbox on a form?

Comment: You would have to build out logic to do that either in your application code or in your SQL code.  Cant provide examples unless you post some table structures, what type of SQL (oracle, SQL Server, other) and what type of programming language and what do you have so far?

Comment: MS access 2016. Table has ID, "ticket description", and "completed date". I want form to allow user to show or hide tickets that have not been completed. Form has a checkbox labeled show/hide tickets, so I have access to a boolean. I want to use that boolean in my query to allow blank dates or not allow blank dates to appear.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the column name is mycol, set your where clause as:

`where (? or mycol is not null) and ...`

Where "?" is the placeholder for the boolean value of the checkbox.